# Mocking passed functional interfaces in spring + Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I was creating tests for methods passed as behaviour, i am not sure how the mocking would work for the funationality. I don't want to mock *executeBehaviour* call but rather the actual execution of the behaviour function.apply

```
 public String processData(){
        String a="check";
        return executeBehaviour((check)->"hello"+check,a);
    }
 public  String executeBehaviour(Function<String,String> data,String data1){
        //Some processing
            return data.apply(data1);
    }
```

I have written the following test case but it does not seem to mock the data.apply()
call.
Test case:

```
  @Test
    void sampleTest() {
        Function<String, String> processFunction = mock(Function.class);
        String test = "check";
        when(groupingFunction.apply(anyString())).thenReturn(test);
        String data = itemInventoryProcessorService.executeBehaviour(processFunction,test);
        Assertions.assertEquals("check", data);
    }
```

The assertion fails as the data written is the actual executed behaviour i.e. "hellocheck" rather than mocked "check".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using doAnswer, we can provide the implementation for the function and return a fake/stubbed result which we are trying to verify. In this manner we are basically providing a stubbing for the function ourselves.

```
 @Test
    void sampleTest() {
        String test = "check";
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Function<String, String> processingFunction = invocation.getArgument(0);
            groupingFunction.apply("dummy");
            return test;
        }).when(itemInventoryProcessorService). executeBehaviour(any(Function.class), anyString());
        var data = itemInventoryProcessorService. processData();
        Assertions.assertEquals("check", data);
    }
```